# Windows ASCII Character/HTML Entity/Unicode

Tags: unicode, ascii, html-entities

I was wondering if there is a HTML entity code or ASCII Character for the windows logo. The one that is visible on the windows key (between <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>).

I would've Google'd it however I did not know what to Google and a lot of the characters can't even be seen on Windows so I wouldn't have known if I had seen it.

One of the reasons I am asking this is so instead of saying <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> I can actually have the logo in there.

If there isn't a logo available, is there one that closely resembles it and can be easily understood.

Also, as a added question but still relevant, is there a client side program that can be installed to see the currently unavailable ascii/unicode/entity characters on Windows?

Comment: The “added question” is very obscure, and should be asked as a separate question, in a clarified form. You should at least specify what you mean by “unavailable”. And the question, being request for a tool, is off-topic at SO; try SuperUser.

Comment: `I was wondering if there is a HTML entity code or ASCII Character for the windows logo.` If the Unicode Consortium added a code-point for the Windows logo, then it would set a precedent for every company to request a character for their companies' logos and their products' logos. It'll never happen. The only option is to use a specialized font, but that only works when using that font; it'll look different when using a different font. As for a font-viewer, yes, you can use the built-in Character Map program (run `charmap`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As explained in [@HansPassant’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22527444/3357935), there is really no adequate way to use the “Windows logo” (more properly called “Windows icon”) as a character. Theoretically, you could use a Private Use codepoint for it, but then you would need a font containing it in that codepoint, and of course this would not work reliably; Private Use codepoints are by definition for use by private agreements and should not be used in public information interchange (though “icon fonts” do just that).

And as mentioned in that answer, the Wingdings font has a “Windows logo” at code point U+00FF, where the letter “ÿ” should be present. This means that you could use

```
<font face=Wingdings>ÿ</font>
```

or, equivalently,

```
<font face=Wingdings>&#xff;</font>
```

Naturally, in any system where a font named Wingdings does not exist, the user would see the letter “ÿ” in the default font. This also happens e.g. in Firefox on Windows, as the browser apparently refuses to play such a font game. Arguably, that’s the correct behavior: if you ask a browser to show a character, say “ÿ”, in a specific font and that font does not contain a glyph for that character, the browser should decline and use another font.

Answer (score 20):

⊞ (U+229E): <kbd>⊞</kbd> or bold <kbd>**⊞**</kbd>.

However, Microsoft has been changing the logo every few versions.

For Windows Vista/7 it looks best in bold italic <kbd>***⊞***</kbd>.

**2021 update:** For Windows 11, the symbol is perfect without formatting!

Answer (score 12):

Company logos are not included in the Unicode character set. For obvious reasons, beyond those companies changing their logo all the time. Like Microsoft did with theirs. You'll want to avoid the marketing department of a company from instantly obsoleting your product :)

You can find non-standard glyphs in one of the symbol fonts, those that map glyphs that are not in the Unicode character set.  On Windows, the logo is included in the Wingdings font, character code U+00FF.  Use the Charmap.exe applet to see it.  It is the olden logo, not the current rectangular one.  Could still be appropriate, the key cap on the user's keyboard might still be the old one as well.  Or in the way a computer user still knows that the icon for the Save command is a floppy disk, even though nobody has ever seen one in the past 10+ years :)  If you put it on a web page then Apple and Linux users are of course unlikely to be happy campers and liable to leave quickly.

A Charmap.exe screenshot:

[image]

Comment: <kbd><font face=Wingdings>ÿ</font></kbd>  for markdown using markdig ! ;-)

Answer (score 8):

`W`  in the Marlett font has the benefit of giving the user the Windows logo version of the machine he is currently using. For instance, on Windows 7:

[image]

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the font replaces that specific glyph with the correct iteration of the logo depending on which Windows version you are running. I find this dubious at best. Can you provide some more screenshots demonstrating the same font on different versions of Windows displaying the desired logo?

Comment: @CannedMan No, my claim was that each version of Windows had an updated version of the font with a matching glyph at that position. However, that doesn't seem to be the case, as the font in Windows 10 still has the Windows 7 version. Windows XP and Vista would have had the same as 7, when rendered in flat monochrome, and earlier versions of the font might not have had that glyph at all, but I'm not sure, since I cannot find any screenshots. In Windows 94, the font certainly didn't have the glyph.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; I probably didn’t read it carefully enough (though I’ve come back to this question three times, not including today, by now).

Answer (score 6):

The closest Unicode symbol I could find was `❖` *(`U+2756` - `BLACK DIAMOND MINUS WHITE X`)*

Answer (score 4):

If the use is for the web you could get symbols by CSS. For example Font Awesome has a [windows symbol](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/windows/) in their font. It's vector graphics so should work in any size.

Would be used in this way:

Inside `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Then in the document:

```
<i class="fa fa-windows" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Answer (score 3):

To address the second question, the tools [BableMap.exe](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html) (free, by Andrew West) and [CharMapEx.exe](https://mihai-nita.net/2007/09/08/charmapex-some-kind-of-character-map/) (free, by Mihai Nita) are useful for font, Unicode, and glyph availability on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

An option is using a **SVG image**.

Result:

[image]

#### Inline SVG

Best option to use once.

```html
<kbd>
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 87.3 87.6" style="width: 11px;">
      <polyline points="0 12.5 35.7 7.6 35.7 42.1 0 42.1"/>
      <polyline points="40 6.9 87.3 0 87.3 41.8 40 41.8"/>
      <polyline points="0 45.74 35.7 45.74 35.7 80.34 0 75.34"/>
      <polyline points="40 46.2 87.3 46.2 87.3 87.6 40 80.9"/>
   </svg>
</kbd>
+
<kbd>R</kbd>
```

#### External SVG

Best option to use multiple times.

HTML file:

```html
<kbd><img src="logo.svg" width="11"></kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
```

`logo.svg`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 87.3 87.6">
   <polyline points="0 12.5 35.7 7.6 35.7 42.1 0 42.1"/>
   <polyline points="40 6.9 87.3 0 87.3 41.8 40 41.8"/>
   <polyline points="0 45.74 35.7 45.74 35.7 80.34 0 75.34"/>
   <polyline points="40 46.2 87.3 46.2 87.3 87.6 40 80.9"/>
</svg>
```